# Should I keep this object alive?

Tags: objective-c, mapkit

MKLocalRequest works as follows:

First, we create an instance: request = [[MKLocalRequest alloc] init];
Then, fire the request: [request startWithCompletionHandler:block], which will call the completion block asynchronously.

Should I keep request alive before the completion block is called?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do so from the perspective of the completion block.  If you don't need the reference any more, don't keep it around.  The general rule is that if an object needs a reference to be alive, it is responsible for declaring (shared) ownership.  This applies to the object itself.  If the request needs to stick around until it can call the completion block, it will create a temporary retain cycle internally.  You don't have to worry about it.

Comment: What you said makes sense, but can you provide any reference to this "general rule"?  "if an object needs a reference to be alive, it is responsible for declaring (shared) ownership"

Comment: Read the memory management guide and the documentation on ARC.  It's the underlying principle for both, though it may not be stated explicitly.

Comment: Can you list another API that shares the same property?

I have ready both documents multiple times.

Comment: What do you mean?  This is one of the underlying principles of Objective-C memory management, that you take ownership (aka retain) while you need the object to remain alive, and you relinquish ownership (aka release) when you no longer need it.  ARC is built on this principle, which is why it uses strong (ownership) and weak (non-ownership).  There is no specific API that works this way.

Comment: It's not clear from the documentation whether the instance of MKLocalRequest is needed to stay alive till the block is invoked.